# how to use dynamic names for webpack 2 import() statements?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, code-splitting

I'm trying to create a library that exposes a function that dynamically imports other libraries based on parameters it gets passed. Something like:

```
export function foo(deps){
  deps.forEach(dep => import(dep).then(doSomething))
}
//usage:
foo(['bar', 'baz']);
```

the library should not know about the deps in advance, but the app using it definitely will and will import foo and any deps.

When i try to create something like this, I get an error saying "module bar not found". I know that webpack uses static analysis to bundle dynamic imports, but I know it can have variables in imports.

If there is a way to list the dependencies ahead of time, that would be fine. I tried something like this (from the app where I use foo)

```
function doNotRun(){
   import('bar');
   import('baz');
}
foo(['bar', 'baz'])
```

in the hopes that webpack would figure out at runtime that it had already bundled this module, but it doesn't seem to match up the module ids. I see bar and baz bundled into chunks, but the actual import uses a different module id.

I also tried making foo aware of all possible deps (by name, but not importing them), and it failed because it needed to know about them at build time. like this:

```
function getImportPromise(subapp){
  switch(subapp){
    case 'baz':
      return import('baz');
    case 'bar':
      return import('bar');
    default:
      return Promise.reject(dep + ' is not known');
  }
}

export function foo(deps){
  deps.forEach(dep => getImportPromise(dep).then(doSomething))
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm asking?

edit:
I just realized that something like my last idea could work, it just feels odd. And more generally, I thought import() could take variables.

```
export function foo(deps, getImportPromise){
  deps.forEach(dep => getImportPromise(dep).then(doSomething))
}

//usage
function getImportPromise(subapp){
  switch(subapp){
    case 'baz':
      return import('baz');
    case 'bar':
      return import('bar');
    default:
      return Promise.reject(dep + ' is not known');
  }
}
foo(['bar', 'baz'], getImportPromise);
```

if this is the recommended solution though, it's not so bad. I was just hoping there was a way to have foo do the import itself.

Comment: Are you looking for `Promise.all(deps.map(dep => import(dep))`? That should work. Having said that, your first solution should work too. If it doesn't then it sounds like a Webpack bug.

Comment: hm i'm not sure about that. the problem is that webpack's static analysis doesn't seem to be able to detect that bar and baz are going to be import()'ed, and so doesn't make separate chunks for them (or even bundle them at all)